# Capture PACKAGE_REMOVED event with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package

I want to capture the event when a package has been removed.
I use the following:
A BroadcastReceiver subclass:

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * This method captures the event when a package has been removed
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Helper.writeInLogFile("Hello from CustomBroadcastReceiver");
        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();         
            if (action.equals(intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED))   {
                //Log the event capture in the log file ...
                Helper.writeInLogFile("The package has been removed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with its manifest section:

```
<receiver android:name="CustomBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

... but the CustomBroadcastReceiver is not fired. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What you have there certainly seems OK, though `intent` will never be `null`, so that particular test is not especially useful.

Comment: Ok for the test - I just did it because I wanted to be sure the action test doesn't fail to an exception sometimes (in fact I secured myself against my ignorance of Android internal messaging system). This said, taking out the whole code, except for the logging into the file, it still doesn't execute CustomBroadcastReceiver ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/aX5-fMbdPR8 under 'hackbod' 2/28/08. In principle, as for any event handler, the CustomBroadcastReceiver instance needs to be registered with the system. That was missing from my code. Of course, the registration (the code in the link above) needs to be done in the main activity class of the application. As a note, if we define the intent filters in the main activity we can just not mention them in the manifest (it doesn't break but it is redundant).